# Recursive print Factorial

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

So I did search and read abut every factorial listing on this site but I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. Iv tried multiple different return methods but they all keep failing. Any ideas?

```
public class RecursivelyPrintFactorial {
    public static void printFactorial(int factCounter, int factValue) {
        int nextCounter = 0;
        int nextValue = 0;

        if (factCounter == 0) // Base case: 0! = 1
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        else if (factCounter == 1) // Base case: print 1 and result
            System.out.println(factCounter + " = " + factValue);
        }
        else { // Recursive case
            System.out.print(factCounter + " * ");
            nextCounter = factCounter - 1;
            nextValue = nextCounter * factValue;
        }

        return factValue * printFactorial(factValue - factCounter);

    }
}

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int userVal = 0;

        userVal = 5;
        System.out.print(userVal + "! = ");
        printFactorial(userVal, userVal);

    }
}
```

I have a feeling I have the equation incorrect in my return but iv tried every combination I can think of. Its driving me insane. Every one reports an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is badly indented, and what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: @laker001 I'm sorry, my intention is for the code to print out the following `5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120` but i get an error when using the following code above. If i leave it as just `return;` I get the following `5! = 5 *` I cannot figure out what needs to be done to get the loop to run properly. I thought I needed a equation but i'm having trouble getting an equation to work.

Comment: you cannot return a value in a void function, you just need to call `printFactorial(...)` in your code to get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return factValue * printFactorial(factValue - factCounter);`

I assume that you should be using the "next" values instead of these.

Edit: Also note that the function takes two parameters and is void. Returning factValue times void doesn't make sense.

Comment: I get an error stating that Void methods cannot return a value when using the `next` values. Is it because they are being used in the loop to be values of the `fact` integers?

Comment: Every time the function is called, it creates new "next" variables in different scopes (so that is not the issue). What you need to do is remove the return line and inside of the final else statement, call `printFactorial(nextCounter, nextValue);`

Comment: :o I only needed to place my method back into me else statement -_- I tried so many different returns and equations.. Cant believe I didn't try that! Thank you very much for the insight and help reed!

Comment: No problem! Note that because the function is void, you shouldn't have any return statements (void means that it doesn't return anything).